# Wordpress Contact form 7 Skip email in before_send hook

Tags: wordpress, hook, contact-form-7

I want to hook in to form submission and check if the email address field has some data then skip the email sending process through CF7 as I'm handling that externally.

My code is below

```
function cornerstonePageFlow ($WPCF7_ContactForm) {
if($WPCF7_ContactForm->id == 10770) {
    $wpcf7      = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $email = $submission->get_posted_data('email');
    if(!empty($email)) {
        $submission->skip_mail = true;
        
    }
}
return $contact_form;
}
add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "cornerstonePageFlow", 10, 3);
```

But this is giving me a fatal error. I cant find anything that explains how to use skip_mail in before send hook. Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the filter `wpcf7_skip_mail`

```
if($WPCF7_ContactForm->id == 10770) {
    $wpcf7      = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $email = $submission->get_posted_data('email');
    if(!empty($email)) {
        add_filter('wpcf7_skip_mail','__return_true');
        
    }
}
```

Alternatively You can use [`skip_mail: on`](https://contactform7.com/additional-settings/#skipping-mail) in the additional settings of the form itself.

Comment: Wouldn't that skip the email for every form submission? I only need to skip email if the user has entered something in the email field in the form

Comment: sorry. will update my answer

Comment: This doesn't work because the moment that filter gets added, it is "stuck" even when the field is empty.